# Focus entry ontop of keyboard

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am working on a Xamarin.Forms PCL app. I am trying to make it so users can comment on posts which displays as the post then scrolling down shows comments with a docked entry at the bottom of the page at all times

I tried

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout>
            <ScrollView>
                <local:PostListView x:Name="Post">

                </local:PostListView>
                <StackLayout>
                    <ListView x:Name="CommentsList">
                    </ListView>
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Padding="10, 5, 10, 10">
            <Entry Placeholder="Comment" BackgroundColor="GhostWhite"/>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Text="Send" HeightRequest="20" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Margin="0, 0, 5, 0"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

but when I click the entry it is covered by the keyboard, is it possible to make it sit above the keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [KeyboardOverlap](https://github.com/paulpatarinski/Xamarin.Forms.Plugins/tree/master/KeyboardOverlap).

#### How it works?

1.Subscibe to keyboard Show/Dismiss events

2.On Keyboard Show

3.Find the Control, which activated the keyboard. (FirstResponder)

4.Determine if keyboard overlaps the Control

5.Calculate how far you need to shift the Page Up

6.Shift the Page Up

7.On Keyboard Dismiss

8.If Page was shifted up, shift the Page Down

Answer (score 1):

For Android you should set:

```
Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Resize);
```

and for iOS:

```
Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOS> ().UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust (WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Resize);
```

Comment: About for iOS ?

Comment: I would set it in the page where there is the entry, for both iOS and Android. Otherwise, are needed custom renderers

Comment: I can't figure out where I add this code? Does it go in the iOS and Android main pages or in the XAML of the page where I need it?

Comment: @Dan Its C#, you have to place it on the page where there is the entry in your shared project.